# MongoEngine: Create Pickle field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mongoengine

I'm using MongoEngine and trying to create a field that works like SQLAlchemy's [PickleType](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) field. Basically, I just need to pickle objects before they're written to the database, and unpickle them when they're loaded.

However it looks like MongoEngine's fields don't provide proper conversion methods I could override, instead having two coercion methods (`to_python` and `to_mongo`). If I understand correctly, these functions can be called anytime, that is, a call to `to_python(v)` does not guarantee that `v` comes from the database. I've thought of writing something like this:

```
class PickleField(fields.BinaryField):
     def to_python(self, value):
        value = super().to_python(value)
        if <<value was pickled by the field>>
            return pickle.loads(value)
        else:
            return value
```

Unfortunately, if I want to be as general as possible, I don't see a way to  check whether the value should be unpickled or not. For instance,

```
a = pickle.dumps(x)
PickleField().to_python(a)  # should return a, will return x
```

I also don't think I can store any state in the PickleField, since that's shared by all instances.

Is there a way around this?